# Half-life of 178m2 Hafnium isotope

Tags: nuclear-physics, isotopes, half-life

Why is the half-life of 178m2 Hafnium isotope 31 years? Maybe it is somehow related to its nuclear spin (16+)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this shows absolutely no research effort.

Comment: Given the answer below gives a reference to a Lawrence Livermore National Lab report, I don't think you will find that level of information on Wikipedia. And, searching is polluted with the 'Hafnium controversy' which is policy, not physics (mainly).

Comment: @heather Fortunately M. J. Steil could answer it without any major problems.

Comment: Isomer not Isotope.  An isomer is an isotope whose nucleus is excited to a higher quantum energy state than its ground state.  An isotope can have more than 1 metastable isomers. The isomer tends to stay in the metastable excited quantum state if there are multiple lower quantum steps to fall through.  This is the case with said isomer. A few nucleons will always tunnel all the way down, but this is statistically low, thus the long half-life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know next to nothing about nuclear isomers but I found this paper: [Theoretical Assessment of 178m2Hf De-Excitation](https://e-reports-ext.llnl.gov/pdf/366265.pdf). It's third section describes the physics of hafnium isomers and on page 13 the authors write:

> The decay of the $16^+$ state is highly suppressed (with a 31 yr
>   half-life) not only because a change of $K$ by at least 8 units is
>   required, but also because the transition has to have a high
>   multipolarity $λ$, due to large angular-momentum differences between
>   the initial ($J= 16^+$) and energetically feasible final states.

To understand this in detail I would recommend reading the entire third section.